# Weakened punishment if done for the nation

Tags: sources-mekorot, sin, reward-punishment, tzibur-community, martyr

I'm looking for sources where we see someone had a lesser punishment or no punishment at all because the act the did although punishable, was done for the nation (klal yisroal).
I heard a shiur where the rebbi mentioned a source or two life this but I don't remember where to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this in Tosfot Yebamot 103a: Gemara says:

> אמר רבי יוחנן שבע בעילות בעל אותו רשע באותו היום שנאמר {שופטים ה-כז} בין רגליה כרע נפל שכב בין רגליה כרע נפל באשר כרע שם נפל שדוד והא קא מתהניא מעבירה אמר רבי יוחנן משום ר''ש בן יוחי כל טובתן של רשעים  רעה היא אצל צדיקים  ‏
>
> Rabbi Johanan Said: That profligate had seven sexual connections on that day; for it is said, Between her feet he sunk, he fell, he lay; at her feet he sunk, he fell; where he sunk there he fell down dead. But, surely she derived gratification from the transgression! Rabbi Johanan replied in the name of Rabbi Simeon Ben Yohai: All the favours of the wicked are evil for the righteous;

Tosfot asks:

> והא קא מתהניא מעבירה. ליכא למימר דפריך אמאי לא מסרה עצמה שהרי קרקע עולם היא כדאמר גבי אסתר ועוד כי הוא לא היה מאנסה ואדרבה היא שדלתו בדברים להכריעו להביאו עליה כדי להתיש כחו **להציל ישראל** אלא פריך אמאי משבחה הכתוב כל כך דכתיב תבורך מנשים וגו' ואמרינן בנזיר (דף כג: ושם) ובהוריות (דף י:) גדולה עבירה לשמה ממצוה שלא לשמה פירוש מאמהות לפי שהיו נהנות מן הביאה ויעל לא היתה נהנית מן הביאה ומשני דודאי לא היתה נהנית משום דטובתן של רשעים כו' ואההיא מילתא קיימא הך פירכא בנזיר (דף כג:) ובהוריות (דף י:):‏
>
> Tosfot says that she was not Karka olam (as the ground of the earth) as the Gemara said about Esther, she was actively participating. So how was it allowed? Why the Gemara in Sanhedrin praise her?
> **Two reasons: *firstly*, this was in order to save lives of Israel, *secondly*, she was not feelling any pleasure**.

Comment: You misrepresent the Tosafot. Tosafot aren't saying that saving a nation is a reason to permit illicit relations. This is not at all a desideratum. Rather, they merely mention is passing that this was her motivation in order to prove that she participate; not that that was why it was halakhically permissible.  || Tosafot neither give one reason to the question, nor two; they don't address it. (perhaps you misread ומשני  and it teaches, to mean "and a second [reason]"

Comment: Tosfot ask about the shevach,  not  about the fact than the shevach imply heiter